# Show that if $z$ is the midpoint of the line segment $[x,y]$ between $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, then $T(z)$ is the midpoint of $[T(x),T(y)]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What does [x,y] represent? Is it a one-dimensional line segment? How is a line segment bounded by x and y if x and y are n-tuples (not numbers on the real number line, for instance)? And what is the "midpoint"?

Moreover, I'm looking for a hint/nudge in the right direction.

Let $T:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^m$ be a linear map. Show that if $z$ is the midpoint of the line segment $[x,y]$ between $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, then $T(z)$ is the midpoint of $[T(x),T(y)]$.

Comment: If you haven't been given definitions of "line segment" or "midpoint", then you're probably expected to infer the right "intuitive" ones. Imagine that $x,y$ are (the position vectors of) points in 2D or 3D. The midpoint $z$ should be the point "directly in between" $x$ and $y$. How should you express the coordinates of $z$ in terms of the coordinates of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Karl I see, so $z=\frac{x-y}{2}$?

Comment: No, $x-z = z-y$

Comment: @beginner almost - that's the vector representing half of the *offset* from $y$ to $x$. To get the *position vector* of the midpoint, you should add $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z$ is midpoint of $[x,y]$ we have $z = {1\over 2}(x+y)$. Since $T$ is linear we have $$T(z) = {1\over 2}T(x+y) = {1\over 2}(T(x)+T(y))$$ so $T(z)$ is midpoint of $[T(x),T(y)]$.

Comment: Thank you very much!